# azure command to copy blob from one directory to another directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azcopy

I am having below structure in my azure.

```
Container
   |-> Application (directory)
           |-> Build (sub directory)
                  |-> Release (Sub directory)
                           |-> build.tar.gz
```

I am planning to change it in below structure so that the build will pick as per the environment.

```
Container
   |-> Application (directory)
           |-> Build (sub directory)
                |-> dev / pre prod / prod (sub directories)
                     |-> Release (Sub directory)
                           |-> build.tar.gz
```

To do the same, I am trying to create a job will copy these builds from dev to pre prod and Pre-prod to prod directory.

Can you suggest the better approach to copy the build from one directory to another in same container.

I have tried with azcopy command to copy file from existing structure to new structure, but it is getting failed as sub directory dev / pre-prod / prod are not available.

> Failed to create one or more destination container(s). Your transfers may still succeed if the container already exists.

Comment: Hi @yogesh you need to send the tar.gz file from structure 1 to structure 2 in the same container with folder dev/pre prod /prod ?

Comment: yes. 
I am trying to create a job which will copy the file from dev to pre prod , pre prod to prod.

But before that I have to copy the tar.gz file from structure 1 to structure 2 (dev directory) using command line

Comment: Are you trying to do this in azure storage?

Comment: yes.. 
All the files is in blob format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I have the same structure as yours in my environment.

**Portal:**

[image]

You can use the below commands to copy the files from structure 1 to structure 2.

**Command:**

```
azcopy copy "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/Application/build/release/sample1.tar.gz?<SAS-token>" "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/Application/build/dev/pre-prod/prod/release/sample1.tar.gz<SAS-token>"  --recursive=true
```

You can get the SAS token from the portal:

[image]
**Output:**

[image]

**Portal:**
The above command executed successfully and copied files from structure 1 to structure 2.

[image]

**Reference:**

[azcopy copy | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Do I need to use same SAS token at both the places ?

Comment: Yes. you need to use in both places.